# Converting an image from JPEG to YUV on android

Tags: java, android, image

This is a really general question. I have a callback that looks like this:

```
public void onCapturedImage(Image image) {
    doSomething(image);
}
```

My problem is that `image` is in JPEG format, and `doSomething()` expects an image in YUV_420_888 
format. The **reverse** conversion has an easy API, but for this direction I couldn't find anything. Due to various considerations, assume it is impossible to configure the system in such a away that image will originally be in YUV.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need a server-side service (Java/ASP/PHP) to send your image file to and get back in the YUV format

Comment: @ControlAltDel this particular application runs entirely on device. No server-side anything.

Comment: I understand that this is just on the device. What I'm saying is that you may need to add a server part to do your image file type conversion

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'd rather not, for various performance reasons.

Comment: You want to do the opposite of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420sp_(NV21)_to_RGB_conversion_(Android)) conversion right?

Comment: @Nicolas - not quite. You've linked to YUV->RGB, I want JPEG->YUV, not RGB->YUV.

Comment: There's a [Java wrapper for handling YUV](https://github.com/Gekkio/robotic-chameleon). JPEG to RGB is easy, it can probably do RGB to YUV. That said I just learned about YUV so I can't do much more.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do it, but it's going to likely require some C.  First, if it's possible, see if you can change doSomething() to use an RGB Bitmap.  If so you can use BitmapFactory or ImageDecoder to convert Image.Plane[0].  That is going to be the easiest solution.

If not, you are going to have to find a libjpeg-turbo library to decompress the JPEG Image to YUV.  Once you get the yuv into a buffer, you can subclass Image to wrap said buffer.

Unfortunately, there is a wrinkle.  The JPEG data may contain a YUV_422_888 image.  If doSomething() can handle that, great!  If not you will need something like libyuv to convert the YUV_422_888 to YUV_420_888.

In short, it's not trivial.  Luckily this transformation is very common in USB Video Camera apps and there are a number of open source examples.